# Syntax error in SQL (IF / EXISTS / CASE / THEN)

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a logging table where I need to insert the status and remark based on the condition below.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT CASE
    WHEN COUNT(A)=COUNT(*))
    THEN --  table has no issues
        STATUS := 'C'
        REMARKS := 'Procedure Completed'
    ELSE -- table has issues
        STATUS := 'F'
        REMARKS := 'Validation Failed'
        END
        FROM table x;
    END IF;
```

On executing this I am facing an error :

```
'SELECT  EXISTS (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(dISTINCT A)=COUNT(*))'
error found ")" (at char 75) expecting `AND' or `AT' or `BETWEEN' or `IN' or `IS'
```

Note:-This process is a part of a store procedure in NETEZZA

Comment: Use a better title for your question

Comment: I removed the extra database tags.  Feel free to add the tag(s) for the database(s) you are actually using.

Comment: I edited the title - try to describe the problem you're having vs. the line of code that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're actually asking a question here, but if your question is, "Why am I getting this error?" then the answer is that you're not using nzplsql syntax. The stored procedure you wrote above looks more like plsql, not nzplsql. I would suggest you read through the [correct syntax](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/r_sproc_nzplqsl_language.html).

To directly state the issues with your code:

- There is no `IF EXISTS`. See [conditional statements](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_conditional_control.html).
- Variables need to be set [in their own statement](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_variables_constants.html), not as part of another select.

If I had to hazard a guess at what you're trying to do, perhaps something like this?

```
sql := 'select 1 from table x having count(a) = count(*);';
execute immediate sql;

if ROWCOUNT = 1 then
  status := 'C';
  remarks := 'Procedure Completed';
else
  status := 'F';
  remarks := 'Validation Failed';
end if;
```